# ffplay -- suppress configuration information on startup

Tags: ffmpeg, bash, ffplay

Is there a way to suppress configuration information when starting ffplay? I know I could redirect to /dev/null but I don't want to lose stderr or stdout. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended way to do this is to add `-hide_banner`. This way, logging is still visible.